# Cannot use chectl auth:login or server:shutdown

Tags: eclipse-che

I am attempting to restart my local eclipse che server after editing some configuration. I attempted to run `chectl server:stop`, but got this error:

```
 »   Error: E_SHUTDOWN_CHE_SERVER_FAIL - Failed to shutdown Eclipse Che server. Login context is not set. Please login
 »   first.
```

So I attempted to login with `chectl auth:login`, but was again presented with an error:

```
Using https://che-che.169.254.109.208.nip.io/api server API URL to log in
    Error: Command failed with exit code 1: oc status
    error: you do not have rights to view project "default" specified in your config or the project doesn't exist
```

I've looked through the documentation, and couldn't find how to create a "default" project

I used `chectl server:deploy --platform=docker-desktop` to start my server.

I have tried other methods of deploying che, but it only worked when using Docker desktop without helm.

I am using Windows 10 home, and deploying it using Docker desktop (Engine v19.03.13) and kubernetes version v1.19.3.

Edit: I have filed a bug report on github: https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/18355

Comment: It seems a bug. 
Could you file an issue [here](https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/new?assignees=&labels=kind%2Fbug&template=bug_report.md&title=)

Comment: Filed here: https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/18355

Thanks!